# invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, int

I met a problem "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' ", which means python cannot convert '' to integers. But I have already added a condition `if(sh.cell_value(rowx=rx, colx=3)!=''):`, which could skip the blocks which contains nothing in the excel. Does anyone have some idea? Thank you very much!

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("streeteasy.xls")
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
total = 0

for rx in range (sh.nrows):
    if(sh.cell_value(rowx=rx, colx=3)!=''):
        s = sh.cell_value(rowx=rx, colx=3)
        print filter(unicode.isdigit, s)
        print int(filter(unicode.isdigit, s))
        total += int(filter(unicode.isdigit, s))
```

Comment: If the error message you cite is the actual one, the string is not empty.  It contains a space.  Also, even if your `if` block doesn't execute, you still continue to the rest of the loop and attempt to call `int` on `s`.

Comment: check `if string.strip()`, which will remove the withe spaces...

Comment: @BrenBarn Unless the post got ninja-edited after your comment, I think you misread. `''` is the empty string - no space.

Comment: @sgpc I added .strip() like: print int(filter(unicode.isdigit, s.strip())), but still doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if block has indentation, hence logical problem.

Corrected version :

```
for rx in range (sh.nrows):
    if(sh.cell_value(rowx=rx, colx=3)!=''):
        s = sh.cell_value(rowx=rx, colx=3)
        print filter(unicode.isdigit, s)
        print int(filter(unicode.isdigit, s))
        total += int(filter(unicode.isdigit, s))
```

in your version , only one statement lies in the if block, and other statements get executed
even with incorrect values :

```
for rx in range (sh.nrows):
    if(sh.cell_value(rowx=rx, colx=3)!=''):
        s = sh.cell_value(rowx=rx, colx=3)
    print filter(unicode.isdigit, s)    # THIS IS NOT INSIDE IF
    print int(filter(unicode.isdigit, s))
    total += int(filter(unicode.isdigit, s))
```

And hence, your code runs over an empty string, or a string containing no digits.

```
>>> s = u"      "
>>> 
>>> 
>>> filter(unicode.isdigit, s)
u''
>>> int(filter(unicode.isdigit, s))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Thanks! I added an if block: if(u!='')

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I suggest you do this.

```
for rx in range (sh.nrows):
    try:
        s = sh.cell_value(rowx=rx, colx=3)
        total += int(s)
    except ValueError:
        if DEBUG_FLAG:
            debug_print("problem: (%d, %d) is '%s'" % (rx, 3, s))
```

You don't need to strip white space from the cell value, if there is any, because `int()` can handle white space.  This will handle any cell value, `''` or anything else.

I got rid of the `filter()` because I'm worried it might do too much.  For example, if you have a cell containing `3.1415` then the `filter()` call would strip out the dot, and you would get `31415` which doesn't seem like a good idea.  Better to have an error than to filter incorrectly.